# Menu Custom link - using relative link when WP is in a subdirectory

Tags: menus, directory

I tend to develop sites in a subdirectory, and I tend to use a fair amount of custom links in my menu ( the "Custom Links" option in the WP admin Appearance > Menus section) to display archive pages.

I am constantly annoyed at the fact that a relative link entered there will not take the subdirectory into account. For example, I have WP is installed in domain.com/dev.

I put a custom link  "/events" in the menu, but it returns domain.com/events, which is 404, instead of properly returning domain.com/dev/events.

How can I change this behavior?

Comment: you need to replace the new url in all the database  after that you able to get  that

Answer (score 2):

`/events` is not a relative link, it's an absolute link.  The beginning slash forces it to the root of the domain.  Of course, a relative link like `events` will be relative to the current page, so if you're on a page like this `domain.com/dev/something/` it'll be `domain.com/dev/something/events`.

If you're developing a WP site that will eventually live at the root of the domain, I suggest you rethink your development process.  Build the site on localhost or a subdomain, so that when you move you don't have to repoint links, just migrate, fix the DB, and go.